# Frames showing on top of othe frames in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a simple GUI with multiple frames in python with tkinter, but what is happening is one frame is showing on top of the other frame. Can anybody help me with why this is and how it can be fixed? Here's my code:
    '''
    SCRATCH GUI
    By Sigton

```
This is a GUI built on Dylan5797's Scratch API
'''

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

import scratchapi

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)

class ScratchGUIApp(tk.Tk):

    '''
    Main backend class, this is what makes stuff work.
    '''

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        ''' Constructor '''

        # Call the parents constructor
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # Set the window title
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Scratch GUI")

        # Create the container
        self.container = tk.Frame(self)
        self.container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        # And configure the grid
        self.container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Create a dictionary of frames and append all pages to it
        self.frames = {}

        for f in (LoginPage, MainPage):

            frame = f(self.container, self)

            self.frames[f] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        # Set the starting page
        self.show_frame(LoginPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        # A simple function to switch pages

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class LoginPage(tk.Frame):

    '''
    This is all content on the login page
    '''

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        ''' Constructor '''

        # Call the parents constructor
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.parent = parent
        self.controller = controller

        # Add the title
        self.title = ttk.Label(self, text="Log in to your Scratch account", font=LARGE_FONT)
        self.title.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2,pady=10)

        # Add the login form
        self.usernameTag = ttk.Label(self, text="Username:")
        self.usernameTag.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="e",pady=2)
        self.usernameEntry = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.usernameEntry.grid(row=1,column=1,pady=2)
        self.passwordTag = ttk.Label(self, text="Password:")
        self.passwordTag.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky="e",pady=2)
        self.passwordEntry = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.passwordEntry.grid(row=2,column=1,pady=2)

        # Just in case theres anything to report
        self.errorMessage = ttk.Label(self, text="", foreground="red")
        self.errorMessage.grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=2,pady=5)

        # Add the disclaimer
        self.subtitle = ttk.Label(self, text="Account information is not collected in any way.")
        self.subtitle.grid(row=4,column=0,columnspan=2)

        # And finally add the login button
        self.button = ttk.Button(self, text="Login",
                                 command= lambda: self.login())
        self.button.grid(row=5,column=0,columnspan=2,pady=10)

    def login(self):

        # Attempts to log the user in to the scratchapi

        usernameData = self.usernameEntry.get()
        passwordData = self.passwordEntry.get()

        if usernameData == "" or passwordData == "":
            # Stop the function if the fields are empty.
            self.errorMessage.config(text="These fields are required.")
            return

        # Attempt to login to the scratchapi with the given username and password

        try:
            scratch = scratchapi.ScratchUserSession(usernameData, passwordData)
        except:
            # Stop the function if there was an error
            self.errorMessage.config(text="Login failed.")
            return

        self.controller.show_frame(MainPage)

class MainPage(tk.Frame):

    '''
    This is all content on the main page.
    '''

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        ''' Constructor '''

        # Call the parents constructor
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.parent = parent
        self.controller = controller

        self.label=ttk.Label(text="hi")
        self.label.pack(in_=self)

app = ScratchGUIApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code is too long. You do not really need to copy+paste the whole project. [SO](http://stackoverflow.com) is a site for more specific questions. Read [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, you have not shown us what you have tried to solve this problem yourself. For more information please visit [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: But it looks like a geometry management issue. I recommend you to start your research with this keyword -- trust me, you'll get plenty of results that are useful for you.

Comment: My apologies, first time using stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The frames are appearing exactly how they should.The problem is that you are putting the "hi" label in the root window, which is also where you put the container for the frames. Even though you use the `_in` parameter, you need to make that label have a parent of `self` due to the way this specific code works (by raising and lowering frames).

Comment: Ah right, I should've put 'self' as a parameter when calling the Label class. Oops. Thanks for the help :)